# Selenium with Firefox and Geckodriver spontaneously failed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Headless firefox with geckodriver scripted with python3 was working perfectly and suddenly fails with the following Error Code 64.

Have made sure to kill all lingering firefox processes and have rebooted serer fresh; still encountering this error on every attempt.

> ```
> options = Options()
> options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"  
> driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options) #, service_log_path='firefox.log')   File
> ```
>
> "/home/user2/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
> line 60, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "/home/user2/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 102, in start
> self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/home/user2/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 115, in assert_process_still_running
> raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
> /home/user2/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64

Latest versions of selenium python module, firefox, and geckodriver:

- geckodriver 0.33.0 (a80e5fd61076 2023-04-02 18:31 +0000)
- Mozilla Firefox 102.15.0esr
- selenium module 4.13.0
- python3.9
- centos7

Answer (score 0):

Discovered problem.  /tmp directory was full.

Was difficult to obtain a diagnostic message.  Was only able to obtain helpful error message when trying to employ a service by executing the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
service = Service()
options = Options()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox" 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.quit()
```